# why overwrite DefaultScheme to "Identity.Application" in asp.net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

below is some source code

```
public class IdentityConstants
{
    private const string IdentityPrefix = "Identity";
    public static readonly string ApplicationScheme = IdentityPrefix + ".Application";
    // ...
}

public static class CookieAuthenticationDefaults
{
   public const string AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
   // ...
}

public static class CookieExtensions
{
   public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCookie(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<CookieAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
      => builder.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, configureOptions);    
   // ...
   public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCookie(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, string? displayName, Action<CookieAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
   {
      builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions>());
      builder.Services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(authenticationScheme).Validate(o => o.Cookie.Expiration == null, "Cookie.Expiration is ignored, ...");
      return builder.AddScheme<CookieAuthenticationOptions, CookieAuthenticationHandler>(authenticationScheme, displayName, configureOptions);
   }
}
```

and I saw source code that uses CookieAuthentication as:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>().AddSignInManager();

        services.AddAuthentication(opts => {
            opts.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;  // <----why not use CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme?
        }).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, opts => {  // <---why set IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme here?
           // ...
        });

    }
    // ...
}
```

I don't understand why we don't use `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` which is "Cookies", and use `IdentityConstants.IdentityConstants` which is "Identity.Application" as the scheme name? Isn't that "Cookies" scheme name is more suitable for Cookie Authentication?

Comment: Hi @user22155685, `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` is intended for Identity framework-related authentication, not for general cookie authentication. Why not using the default Identity?